# What is the relevant asymptotic when regressing rates?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, inference

Suppose I am modeling some quantity $y$ as a function of a covariate $x$, using a model from the linear family.
$$ y = \beta x + \epsilon $$

For simplicity let's assume $x$ is categorical with $2$ values. I can then interpret my estimated coefficient $\beta$ as follows: if I take a sample where $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, on average their difference will be $\beta$. As the sample size grows, this difference gets closer and closer to $\beta$.

How does this work if $y$ is a rate? Now there are $2$ quantities that can grow - the exposure (denominator in the rate) and the number of times I measure that rate. Which is it that needs to grow so that the difference gets closer to $\beta$?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest exploring a power-transformation ([like Box-Cox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation)) as it is likely that the error structure assuming $y$ is an observed ratio, is not normally distributed, or would the error terms likely have a homogeneous error variance.

Note, assuming, for example, a natural log transform, when constructing prediction intervals, the center of the interval upon taking the reverse transform, actually corresponds to a median if the original error terms were [Log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Related interpretation issues could occur upon reversing a power transformation.